# How to "Enable Super User Access" for users with Partner Community license

Tags: community

I am trying to enable Super User Access for Communities (Partner), and I am following documentation here:

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_partner_super_user_access.htm&language=en_US

I have gone to Setup--Customize--Communities--Settings and have checked "Enable Partner Super User Access".  I also have one role enabled.  I then go to a Contact and choose Manage External User--View Partner User.  When I get to the User I see a checkbox that is NOT checked for "Partner Super User".  When I edit the user that checkbox is not available to edit. How do I get that box checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update the existing users, go to the the User's Contact page (Manage External User -> Enable Super User Access)

Alternatively, or if you have to do this in large batches, you can do it via the API.

1. Open Developer Console
2. Select Debug->Open Execute Anonymous Window
3. enter a short piece of code like the below:

   `User u =new User(Id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',IsPrmSuperUser = true);
   update u;`

If you want any new portal user to automatically become a superuser, you could implement a trigger on User. Make sure the method in which you do the update has @future context. Example of the method to call in your trigger:

```
@future
private static void updateUsers(Set<Id> users){
    List<User> usersToUpdate = new List<User>();

    for(Id userId : users){
        User u = new User(Id=userId);
        u.IsPrmSuperUser = true;
        usersToUpdate.add(u);
    }
    update usersToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Guy, thanks for the answer.  Updating the User record via code works as you say.  However, even though I've enabled Partner Super User Access in the Communities Settings, when I create a new Partner User (from Contact record -- Manage External User -- Enable Partner User), the new user is not a Partner Super User.  Also, when I view the new user there is no button that allows me to make them a Partner Super User. And when I edit the user, the checkbox is not avail.

Comment: My bad, I did not realize we actually implemented an APEX trigger that automatically upgrades any portal user to superuser. I'll update my answer..

Comment: Guy, thanks for the update.  It's good to hear that you experienced the same thing we are.  I will reach out to my contacts at Salesforce and see if there is any more info, and will share if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the lightning process builder gives access to check this one. So you can set up a lightning process at creation of the user to set the flag.